# "const not supported in strict mode" on Safari when "const" is not in my compiled javascript bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack with babel loader to compile a react/es6 javascript front end. This is for a node Express application

The javascript works on on all modern browsers however breaks when using Safari version 8 and bellow. It produces the following error message :

> [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations
>   are not supported in strict mode. (anonymous function) (app.js.gz,
>   line 1)

As mentioned, my compiled javascript does not have any use of the word "const", other than in comments. The question is what is causing this error, and how do I resolve it?

I have tried excluding and including node modules, changing lets/consts in my uncompleted code to vars, and a number of webpack configurations like production mode/uglify-minimise/remove-comments non of which work.

The only option I can think of is that my node server is somehow the issue, as it is the only code that contains "const" references. If this could be the problem can you explain why, as this code should not be hitting the client as far as I am aware.

Here is my webpack code:

[image]

Here is the line the error occurs on :

[image]

Node Version : v8.9.4

Webpack : 3.10.0

Comment: What file and line number did it reference? What did you find there?

Comment: updated the error message to show the error line number as 1124

Comment: So what’s on line 1124 of app.js.gz? (Click on the link in the console.)

Comment: Updated the question, as although that const was resolved a new (more obscure "const" error has been caught)

Comment: Was this originally minified? Please turn off minification to get an accurate line number. (I don’t know if Safari supports source maps but the more potential for confusion that can be eliminated, the better.)